# ios - naming and make action from each cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

So I'm using this code... "MFSideMenuDemoStoryboard"
https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu/tree/master/Demos/MFSideMenuDemoStoryboard/MFSideMenuDemoStoryboard

And I want to give a name to each cell in the "SideMenuViewController.m" and make each one of these cells show a specific UIView in the "DemoViewController.m". any help with that ?

any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: what do you mean? I've been trying for 2 days, but it is not working for me! I tried to make every cell a button and then use the button to change view also and it didnt work so i understood that im in the wrong way, thats why im asking help here!

Comment: OK. I meant code example of what you currently have ? So we can see what could be wrong. It's hard to just guess an answer for you.

Comment: Also it seems you are trying to use this sample for something that it isn't design for. this is supposed to be used to change UIViewControllers NO adding different UIViews to a specific UIViewController

Comment: That being said, it shouldn't be too difficult to re-purpose.

Comment: See my answer .... I think I understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In `SideMenuController`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DemoViewController *demoController = [[DemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoViewController" bundle:nil];
    demoController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Demo #%d-%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:demoController];
    navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
```

}

Replace this code with something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //EDIT #1
    UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
    DemoViewController *currentCenterView = [[navigationController viewControllers] firstObject];
    [currentCenterView addAnotherView:indexPath.row]; //This is where you will tell your 'middle view' to load another UIView ... You can use the indexPath.row to determine which option was tapped and act accordingly.

    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
```

}

You obviously need to add a method `- (void) addAnotherView:(NSInteger ) row;` to your `DemoViewController` or whatever you've called it.

Edit #1 this will reference the current loaded view. This will only work if you are only using 1 view controller on the navigation controller stack. Otherwise grabbing the first object won't work and you'll need to search for the right index.

Comment: You said " [demoController addAnotherView:indexPath.row]; //This is where you will tell your 'middle view' to load another UIView ... You can use the indexPath.row to determine which option was tapped and act accordingly. "   ... how do I do that can you help me?

Comment: Are you using the project that you linked to ? If so in the DemoViewController.h add: - (void) addAnotherView:(NSInteger ) row;

Comment: Then in the .m add: - (void) addAnotherView:(NSInteger ) row { //this is where you add your view }

Comment: See my edit. That's because I deleted the declaration of the demoController object.

Comment: now i get 2 errors that says,  No known class method for selector 'viewControllers'.  and " Unknown receiver 'navigationController'; did you mean 'UINavigationController'? "

Comment: Deleted the navigation controller declaration. added this in now

Comment: okay so now there's no errors... I write this in DemoViewController.m ==> '- (void) addAnotherView:(NSInteger ) row{
        
    DemoViewController *currentCenterView = ViewController1;
    DemoViewController *currentCenterView = ViewController2;

}'  but how do i use the indexpath.row to relate it to the cells ?

Comment: CW0007007 can you help me please with the method!

Comment: what ? What is  DemoViewController *currentCenterView = ViewController1; DemoViewController *currentCenterView = ViewController2; supposed to do ? whats viewController1/2 ?\

Comment: Well the indexPath tells you which cell was pressed.. so what are you trying to achieve in the addAnotherView method ?

Comment: lets say i have viewcontroller1 and view controller2 (or you suggest that i use UIViews? view1 and view2 ??) and when i press first cell i want to see the viewcontroller1 or view1 (depends what you suggest me to use better) and when i press 2nd cell to show the viewcontroller2/view2, and etc... how do i do that?? i dont understand the indexpath! i dont know how to use it, i also want to know how can i give each cell a different title for example! thank you, your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Oh that's not what your question asked. In which case ignore everything I've done and just use the code that in the sample .. I'm not sure how else to explain it... it's all written for you you just need to look and see how it works ...

Comment: The cells get their title from the tableview data source.